# Disable autostart of integrated webserver in visual studio 2005

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webserver

Is there a way to run a project inside a solution that has more one project (read: web applications) and avoid the autostart feature of the integrated asp.net webserver in Visual Studio?

I have a big solution that has Windows forms projects, Windows Services projects, Web applications, Windows Libraries etc., sometimes I just want to debug the desktop application but each web application project starts a webserver and that slows down the execution process (when starting the application of course) and I would like those webservers to be disabled since im not using/debuging those projects but some other developers in my team are.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the project you don't want to start up automatically in solution explorer and in the properties pane set "Always Start When Debugging" to false

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a new solution with only the project(s) you are working on.